# Copy the toplink from the footer to the header Magento

Tags: toplinks, topmenu

I have a template with the toplinks (My Account, My Wishlist, My Cart, Checkout, Log In ) in footer by default but I want also compare in header.

The theme is "trego" (please view)

I pasted  `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLinks’) ?>` from footer to header in more more class but in never compare the toplinks.

I do not understand why.

This is `header.phtml` :

```
<div class="header-container">
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-bground">
        <div class="header-sidebar">
            <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
            <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
            <?php else:?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
            <?php endif?>
            <div class="box-scroll">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch'); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSpecialMenu'); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('socialIcons'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyrights'); ?>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filterproducts-link">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-topbar">
        <div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_currency_selector') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_cartheader') ?>
        </div>
        <h1 class="page-title"></h1>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="filterproducts-overlay" style="display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 98; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="filterproducts col1-layout" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="special_menu">
        <?php
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            $code  = $store->getCode();
            $enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/new/active',$code);
            if($enable == 1){
        ?>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a_latest"><span><?php echo $this->__('Latest'); ?></span><span class="expander">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        <?php
            }
            $enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/featured/active',$code);
            if($enable == 1){
        ?>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a_featured"><span><?php echo $this->__('Featured'); ?></span><span class="expander">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        <?php
            }
            $enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/special/active',$code);
            if($enable == 1){
        ?>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a_special"><span><?php echo $this->__('Specials'); ?></span><span class="expander">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">Close</a>
        <span class="page-controls">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-prev">Prev</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-next">Next</a>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('filterproducts');?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.header-topbar h1.page-title').html(jQuery('.main .page-title h1').html());
            /*
            if(jQuery(window).width()>1007){
                jQuery('.box-scroll').niceScroll({zindex : 51, objfixed: true});
            }
            */
            jQuery('html').niceScroll({zindex : 9999});
            var ajax_loaded1 = false;
            var ajax_loaded2 = false;
            var ajax_loaded3 = false;

            jQuery('.a_latest').click(function(){
                if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').hide();
                    jQuery('.filterproducts').css('left', ((jQuery(window).width()-760)/2)+"px");
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#new_products').addClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#new_products').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.special_menu li a').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('.a_latest').addClass('active');
                    if(!ajax_loaded1){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('filterproducts/index/newproduct',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>",
                            context: document.body
                        }).done(function(msg) {
                            jQuery('div#new_products').html(msg);
                            ajax_loaded1 = true;
                            if(jQuery(window).height() < 925 ){
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '394px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-479)/2)+"px");
                            } else {
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '788px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-873)/2)+"px");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            jQuery('.a_featured').click(function(){
                if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').hide();
                    jQuery('.filterproducts').css('left', ((jQuery(window).width()-760)/2)+"px");
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#featured_products').addClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#featured_products').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.special_menu li a').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('.a_featured').addClass('active');
                    if(!ajax_loaded2){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('filterproducts/index/featured',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>",
                            context: document.body
                        }).done(function(msg) {
                            jQuery('div#featured_products').html(msg);
                            ajax_loaded2 = true;
                            if(jQuery(window).height() < 925 ){
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '394px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-479)/2)+"px");
                            } else {
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '788px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-873)/2)+"px");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            jQuery('.a_special').click(function(){
                if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').hide();
                    jQuery('.filterproducts').css('left', ((jQuery(window).width()-760)/2)+"px");
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#special_product').addClass('active');
                    jQuery('div#special_product').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.special_menu li a').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('.a_special').addClass('active');
                    if(!ajax_loaded3){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('filterproducts/index/special',  array('_secure' =>  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure())) ?>",
                            context: document.body
                        }).done(function(msg) {
                            jQuery('div#special_product').html(msg);
                            ajax_loaded3 = true;
                            if(jQuery(window).height() < 925 ){
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '394px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-479)/2)+"px");
                            } else {
                                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '788px');
                                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-873)/2)+"px");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            jQuery('.filterproducts-link').click(function(){ jQuery('.a_latest').click(); });
            jQuery('.filterproducts a.close').click(function(){
                jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').fadeOut();
                jQuery('div.filterproducts').fadeOut();
                jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').fadeOut();
                jQuery('.special_menu li a').removeClass('active');
            });
            jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').click(function(){
                jQuery('div.filterproducts').children('div').fadeOut();
                jQuery('div.filterproducts').fadeOut();
                jQuery('div.filterproducts-overlay').fadeOut();
                jQuery('.special_menu li a').removeClass('active');
            });
            var scrollHeight = 788;

            if(jQuery(window).height() < 925){
                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '394px');
                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-479)/2)+"px");
                scrollHeight = 394;
            } else {
                jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '788px');
                scrollHeight = 788
                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-873)/2)+"px");
            }
            jQuery(window).resize(function(){
                jQuery('.filterproducts').css('left', ((jQuery(window).width()-760)/2)+"px");
                if(jQuery(window).height() < 925 ){
                    jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '394px');
                    scrollHeight = 394;
                    jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-479)/2)+"px");
                } else {
                    jQuery('.filterproducts div.category-products').css('height', '788px');
                    scrollHeight = 788
                    jQuery('.filterproducts').css('top', ((jQuery(window).height()-873)/2)+"px");
                }
                if(jQuery(window).width() < 768){
                    jQuery('.filterproducts a.close').click();
                }
                /** for SAMSUNG GALAXY TABLET */
                if(jQuery(window).width()>=768 && jQuery(window).width()<=1024){
                    jQuery('.header-container').css('width', jQuery(window).width()+"px");
                } else {
                    jQuery('.header-container').css('width', '');
                }
                /** for SAMSUNG GALAXY TABLET */
            });
            jQuery('.filterproducts a.page-next').click(function(){
                jQuery(".filterproducts div.active div.category-products").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".filterproducts div.active div.category-products").scrollTop()+scrollHeight}, 600, "easeOutCubic");
                return false;
            });
            jQuery('.filterproducts a.page-prev').click(function(){
                jQuery(".filterproducts div.active div.category-products").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".filterproducts div.active div.category-products").scrollTop()-scrollHeight}, 600, "easeOutCubic");
                return false;
            });
            jQuery("html").click(function(){
                if(jQuery(window).width()<=1024){
                    jQuery("#nav li span.plus").each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('expanded');
                        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
                        jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').slideUp('fast');
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add `topLinks` in a layout file as a child for the `header` block?

Comment: i have added this in header only:  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLinks’) ?>

Comment: Was the `topLinks` php call enclosed in a Div? I would look at copying the surrounding code to the header as well. I moved my `topLinks` area and lost formatting without this container.